# How do I make parts of a texture transparent in Max?

Tags: textures, 3dsmax, transparency

I am applying an `eye.psd` eye-texture to my character model's face, but the results aren't what I'm expecting.

Here's what it looks like (Observe the eye on the right. Ignore the other one.):

[image: Max screenshot showing eye within white rectangle]

The image is attached to a quad. I want to either

- change the color of the blank area to the skin color, as it is nearby, or
- make the image be the shape of the eye instead of square?

As shown, my image is a square and parts of it show as white, even though I erased them in Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop screenshot of eye texture]

I expected this area to be skin-coloured:

[image]

How can I make this work right?

Comment: Ah, that should work as you expected it to do. What kind of image format are you using? Or do you somehow paste the image through the clipboard? If so, the transparency might get lost in the process. Try saving the image as a PNG (or any other format supporting transparency) and then importing that into 3dsmax (haven't used it for ages; and even then it's only been some light version though).

Comment: I don't really feel that this question really belongs on this site. This question is about 3D modelling, not game development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [opacity map](http://makeitcg.com/using-opacity-maps-in-3ds-max/476/)!
Simply trace the outline of the eye in Photoshop, and make the "visible" part of the texture white, and the part you want invisible black.

Then inside 3DS Max, go to your texture's mapping channels and insert the black and white image into "Opacity Map"—and voila! No more silly whiteness.

---

P.S. The reason the black space shows up as white on your model, is because 3DS Max doesn't know how to deal with the blank space on this occasion, as you haven't told it what to do. Hence it simply displays it with the default colour, which is white.